# There was no endpoint listening at https://XXXXXX/XXXX.svc - The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden

Tags: web-services, https, iis-10

Our client is getting below error when they try to call the web service via HTTPS request.

'There was no endpoint listening at https://XXXXXX/XXXX.svc - The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.'

But the interesting part is, client successfully connects using the port which was used by the previous version. But new ports are not working. which means still client can call the new service using the old port. But once we change the bindings to the new https port, client is getting above error.

Below checks have been completed already.

1) Client can successfully access the URL from their server.
2) No firewall rules placed for the newly created port.
2) SSL root certificates are placed in the Trusted Root Certification folder.

Please let me know if you have any idea regarding this issue?

Thank you

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/diagnostics/tracing/configuring-tracing Usually people get started from tracing.

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, it seems that you may missed the https setting in the wcf application web.config file.

The following is a complete example of a web.config file for a WCF service using HTTPs.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>  
<configuration>  

  <system.web>  
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />  
  </system.web>  
  <system.serviceModel>  
    <services>  
      <service name="MySecureWCFService.Service1">  
        <endpoint address=""  
                  binding="basicHttpBinding"  
                  bindingConfiguration="secureHttpBinding"  
                  contract="MySecureWCFService.IService1"/>  

        <endpoint address="mex"  
                  binding="mexHttpsBinding"  
                  contract="IMetadataExchange" />  
      </service>  
    </services>  
    <bindings>  
      <basicHttpBinding>  
        <binding name="secureHttpBinding">  
          <security mode="Transport">  
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>  
          </security>  
        </binding>  
      </basicHttpBinding>  
    </bindings>  
    <behaviors>  
      <serviceBehaviors>  
        <behavior>  
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->  
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true"/>  
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->  
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>  
        </behavior>  
      </serviceBehaviors>  
    </behaviors>  
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />  
  </system.serviceModel>  
  <system.webServer>  
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>  
  </system.webServer>  

</configuration>
```

More details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-configure-an-iis-hosted-wcf-service-with-ssl).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your time all.
Proxy Server was blocking the requests come through the specific ports. Issue has been resolved after adding the ports into the proxy server.